# Connect QPushButton of QWizardPage with NextButton of QWizard

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

how could I connect a QPushButton of a QWizardPage with the Next Button of Qwizard?

What I want is: when I click in the QPushButton created in the QWizardPage, the page goes to the next screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pageButton` is your page button, just:

```
pageButton.clicked.connect(wizard.button(QWizard.NextButton).click)
```